# How can I do to put a tab after \a in my text using sed?

Tags: sed

I would like to add `'file2'` below `'file1'`. Here is my file :

```
'file1'
```

And I would like something like that :

```
'file1'
    'file2'
```

I tried something like that :

```
sed "/'file1',/a\/t'file2'," myfile.py
```

but the tab is not working.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have issues with the tab char.

You can use

```sh
sed "/'file1'/a\
\\"$'\t'"'file2'" myfile.py > outputfile.txt
```